# The async attribute is ignored if the <script> tag has no src?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

The async attribute is ignored if the  tag has no src? Because defer is, but i cant fin information about async.

Comment: [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attributes): _"For classic scripts, if the `async` attribute is present, then the classic script will be **fetched in parallel** to parsing and evaluated as soon as it is available."_ - The attribute influences the way/order a script is fetched. If there's no script to fetch (no `src="..."`) the attribute doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

This attribute affects javascript fetching. If you have no src there is nothing to fetch.

Also you can do a simple test to check how it works. Spoiler: it doesn't do anything as expected.

```html
<script>
  console.log("sync 1")
  console.log(document.getElementById('test') != null)
</script>

<script async>
  console.log("async")
  document.write('<div id="test"></div>')
</script>

<script>
  console.log("sync 2")
  console.log(document.getElementById('test') != null)
</script>
```

Comment: So if i add dynamic script in <script async> (like google tag manager) </script> that will do nothing?

Comment: GTM has inline (sync) script that adds another script elements that do have src and are marked as async. And it makes perfect sense: the real tag manager script will be loaded asynchronously. If you mark GTM init script itself as async it will have no effect.